# ssh passwordless login from windows to linux fails

Tags: ssh

I am sure this has been asked many times, for some reason I have still problem with getting it to work.

I have a generated public and private key on my windows machine and copied the public key:

```
ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub ekamolid@host
```

then on the server I did:

```
chmod 700 .ssh
chmod 644 authorized_keys
```

on local machine I run:

```
chmod 600 id_rsa
```

`sshd_config` file has:

- `RSAAuthentication yes`
- `PubkeyAuthentication yes`

I restarted ssh server on remote server.

when try:

```
ssh ekamolid@host
```

I get following error in `/var/log/secure`:

> Feb 17 06:36:56 bur00cpw sudo: pam_unix(sudo:auth): authentication failure; logname=ekamolid uid=0 euid=0 tty=pts/3 ruser= rhost=  user=ekamolid

What am I missing here?

Comment: authorized_keys contains line from id_rsa.pub ? file is not in dos mod ? chmod 600 id_rsa (not 700) ?

Comment: @Archemar I just changed chmod to 600. it is very possible is might be in dos mode, I wonder if changin it to linux on linux server would be fine. What do you think

Comment: @Archemar I just tried dos2unix without any luck.

Comment: no more idea sorry, yet either use ssh-copy-id or change ownership yourself.

Comment: It turned out to be ssh on windows issue, I installed cygwin and issue is gone now.

Comment: Elbek, if you put that as an answer and accept it, your issue becomes potentially more useful for others to find in the future. Especially if you can edit your question to explain what you were using before you installed Cygwin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be ssh on windows issue, I installed cygwin and issue is gone now.

Answer (score 0):

`chmod go-w $HOME` is another requirement.

And why not use 600 instead of 644 for the `authorized_keys`?

Regards,
Philipp.